# Why does my code throw an exception when I try to scan using WIA?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm making an application on C# Winforms which scans documents and places them into a PictureBox, However when I attempt to scan it throws an exception saying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" and will not allow me to continue,  the stack trace is  as below;

To clarify, this is a work project in case anyone gets alarmed by some of the class names.

```
AbDesktop.exe!AbDesktop.FrmCreditCards.ScanSetup() Line 39  C#
    AbDesktop.exe!AbDesktop.FrmCreditCards.ScanFrontBtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 94 + 0x8 bytes    C#
    [External Code] 
    AbDesktop.exe!AbDesktop.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 26 + 0x20 bytes    C#
    [External Code]
```

this is the code that is causing the issue;

```
 public void ScanSetup()
 {
     WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
     ImageFile scannedImage=null;

     scannedImage = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(
         WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
         WiaImageIntent.UnspecifiedIntent,
         WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality,
         FormatID.wiaFormatPNG,
         true, true, false);
     scannedImage.SaveFile("C:/Users/reece.cottam/Pictures");
 }
```

and this is the button that executes the above code when the click event is fired

```
private void ScanFrontBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScanSetup();
    ImageFile IF = new ImageFile();
    FrontScanBox.Image = IF.LoadFile("scannedimage.png");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***
The line of code causing the error is ScannedImage.Savefile

Comment: Which line throws the exception? What does the stack trace look like? *Always* give this information in a question with an exception...

Comment: I think you are loading an image from the current directory,and you didnt scanned it there.

Comment: I see! How do I resolve this then?

Answer (score 1):

Without extra information about which line throws the exception, I would guess that it's the line `scannedImage.SaveFile(...);` since the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `CommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage(...)` states that a null value may be returned. In this case, when you try to operate on the variable `scannedImage`, you could be attempting to operate on a null reference.

Comment: Did you answer @JonSkeets question? It's difficult to help you without that info.

Comment: That only tells us the line number in relation to the entire class, it's not very helpful when we only have a snippet of code, can you identify the line of code in the question?

Comment: Done =] the line of code causing the error is scanned Images.SaveFile

Comment: @ReeceCottam as Samuel Slade said the documentation explains it: _Returns an ImageFile object on success, otherwise returns Nothing._ So you're invoking a method on an object which could be null (if the scan failed) without checking if the object exists. Check if the scan failed / the object is null and act accordingly.

Comment: ahh I see! thanks for the explanation I'm new to c# =] that explains why this problem occurs when scanning, but when I close the dialog box for scanning it throws the same exception, which is why I'm slightly confused because it shouldn't be scanning if all I want to do is close the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is pretty clear, the **ShowAcquireImage** method *Returns an ImageFile object on success, otherwise returns Nothing.*.

**scannedImage** is null because this method was not successful, you need to look at the parameters you are passing in here, read the documentation and adjust them appropriately until you are getting the image you want back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying an actual file, instead of just the directory to save to?

```
scannedImage.SaveFile("C:/Users/reece.cottam/Pictures/test.png");
```

The lack of a decent filename might cause errors in the SaveFile function.
Though that should be visible in the Exception details.

Comment: indeed I have, and nothing changes